How to configure Apache FOP (using xsl-fo) to use a RGB-icc file to produce PDF/UA with enough contrast to meat Accessible standards
I want to use RGB colors in PDF in order to  produce PDF/UA with enough contrast to meat Accessible standards for a page-number in orange.
I have tried several options like the one in this question:
Add to the FOP.conf file in the
<renderer mime="application/pdf"> section
<filterList>
  <output-profile>AdobeRGB1998.icc</output-profile>
</filterList>

An other one I have tried is the option to use
<fo:declarations>
  <fo:color-profile src="url('AdobeRGB1998.icc')" color-profile-name="adobeRGB_98"/>
</fo:declarations>

And then reference it with color="rgb-icc(255,127,0,adobeRGB_98)"
The actual color I need looks like this:

And the color I now have in PDF is this:

I assume the last one is coveted to cymk and has not enough contrast according WCAG 2.0
We are using FOP version 2.10
When I use Xep with there option using a processing-instruction like this
<xsl:processing-instruction name="xep-pdf-icc-profile">url(AdobeRGB1998.icc)</xsl:processing-instruction>
The same pagenumber gives no validation errors.
I am using PAC 2024 to validate against PDF/UA.


It seems that you would need to add it to the FOP configuration. See:
https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/configuration.html#pdf-renderer

I have tried that one without success

I don't use FOP, so that was all that I know.

As it turns out, that orange color will never have enough contrast. In the Xep-version the headers and footers were all marked as Artifacts and therefore not checked against contrast rules.
So by adding the @role='artifact' to the static-content parts like this example:
<fo:static-content flow-name="region-after-portrat" role="artifact" font-size="9pt">
  <fo:block color="#FF8000">
    <fo:page-number/>
  </fo:block>
</fo:static-content>

no contrast-validation errors anymore.
